# I have used cypress-drag-drop plugin and my test get passed but it does not do any action. how to solve this?

Tags: cypress

From the excluded section, the ALO element should move to the selected section by this code but it was not moving.

My code:

```
('drag and drop',()=>{
   cy.datacy('search').type('BeSt-Derivate AG');
   cy.datacy('customerName').should('have.text', ` ${'BeSt-Derivate AG'} `)
  .and('be.visible').click().wait(200);
   cy.get("mat-tab-header").contains("Configuration").click();
   cy.datacy('createAP').invoke('show').click().wait(2000)
   cy.datacy('alo').last().drag('[data-cy="selected"]', 'center');
})
```

A screenshot of the issue:

[image: image1]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the code is correct for using the drag-drop plugin. In such situation would try to look for a possible update on the plugin and version compatability with my version of Cypress. Since Updating to cypress 5.5 I had a lot of problems with plugins and It was trial and error to find the right one. The one working for me is drag-drop version 1.3.1. The 1.4 version of the plugin totally didn`t work